# Function that returns index of Forex candle according opening hours (weekly session)

Tags: python, datetime

The output of the function is as desired. When Forex opens at Sunday, first candle is annotated with 1 and the number increments with every new candle, till weekend, when the imaginary counter is reset.

I am aware of those risks (it is solved elsewhere):

- passed datetime must be python datetime
- time must be in GMT

My concerns are about readability and optimality of the code. Any advice?

```
def weektag_from_time(timestamp, freq):
    """
    This function returns index of the current time in Forex session,
    according to chosen granularity.
    Forex session - Sunday 2200 to Friday 2200.
    If the session is off, it should return 0.

    Args:
        * timestamp : python datetime in GMT
        * freq : desired granularity (minute, hour, ...)

    Returns:
        * weektag : integer index in Forex session
    """
    # init
    assert freq in ["H1", "M1"], "Required granularity is not known."
    d = timestamp.weekday()
    h = timestamp.hour
    m = timestamp.minute
    # get tag
    if (d == 5) or (d == 4 and h > 21) or (d == 6 and h < 22):
        # market is closed
        weektag = 0
    else:
        # estimate week day offset in hours and add it to current day hours
        offset = (24*d)+2 if d < 6 else -22
        h += offset
        # set result according granularity
        if freq == "H1":
            weektag = h
        elif freq == "M1":
            weektag = (h*60) + m
    return weektag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code overall is readable and well documented. Of course, there is always something to improve, here are some things:

- the frequencies are currently hardcoded in the function and the "assert" *is not actually a strong check* and would not prevent an invalid `freq` value to be used if [Python compilation is optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1838411/771848). I'd define frequencies in an [`Enum` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html):

  ```
  from enum import Enum


  class Frequency(Enum):
       HOURLY = "H1"
       MINUTELY = "M1"
  ```

  Then, as a bonus, if you would use variable type annotations, your IDE would warn you if you would pass an invalid frequency to the `weektag_from_time()` function.
- use `day`, `hour` and `minute` in place of more questionable `d`, `h` and `m` - remember, we are writing programs for people to read, not computers
- I would improve on the "is market closed" check defining individual conditions in separate variables (the ["Extract Variable" refactoring method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractVariable.html)), something like

  ```
  is_saturday = day == 5
  is_late_friday = day == 4 and hour > 21
  is_early_sunday = day == 6 and hour < 22

  market_closed = is_friday or is_late_thursday or is_early_saturday
  ```
- or, may be even easier and more understandable would be to define an open market time range and reverse the logic. And, it might be a good idea to extract this check into a separate reusable function (I'm sure you have this kind of check in other parts of your project).
- now, we may use an early "return" if market is closed and omit the "else" part decreasing the nestedness:

  ```
  if market_closed:
      return 0

  offset = (24 * day) + 2 if day < 6 else -22
  hour += offset

  # set result according granularity
  if freq == Frequency.HOURLY:
      return hour
  elif freq == Frequency.MINUTELY:
      return (hour * 60) + minute
  ```
- according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id28), you should have *spaces around operators*
- the `offset` calculation logic probably needs more explanation - consider adding an extra comment explaining the idea behind calculating it